# Postgresql fails to start

Tags: linux, postgresql, debian

Postgresql fails to start

> when I run `sudo -u postgres psql` I get the following output

```
psql: could not connect to the server: No such file or directory
It really works locally and receives
Connection via domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

> postgresql.conf

```
listen_addresses = '*'
```

> pg_hba.conf

```
# Database administrative login by Unix domain socket
local all postgres trust
# TYPE DATABASE USER ADDRESS METHOD
# "Local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local all all trust
# IPv4 local connections:
host all all 0.0.0.0/32 trust
host all all 192.168.0.0/24 trust
# IPv6 local connections:
host all all :: 1/128 trust
```

> When I try to manually start the server `sudo service postgresql start` I get the following output

```
[....] Starting PostgreSQL 9.1 database server: main [....] 
The PostgreSQL server failed to start. Please check the log output: 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ???????: ?? selinux selinux media IPv6: EAFNOSUPPORT 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ???????: ?? selinux ??????????? ? ?????? bin dev etc lib mnt opt ​​run srv sys tmp usr var ???????? ??????????: EADDRNOTAVAIL 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ???????: media selinux ?????? bin dev etc lib mnt opt ​​run srv sys tmp usr var ???????? lost + found 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ???????: ?? selinux selinux media bin dev etc lib mnt opt ​​run srv sys tmp usr var ???????? ??????????: EAFNOSUPPORT 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ???????: selinux lost + found ??????????? ?? - ?? ???????? ???????? ?????? 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ??????????????: ??????????? ?? ???????? ?? - ?? ???????????? ???????????? 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ?????????: ???????? ???????? "Track_counts". 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ???????: selinux boot home proc root sbin ???????????? "/etc/postgresql/9.1/main/pg_hba.conf" ?? ???????: EACCES 
2015-06-04 17:44:22 UTC ????? 
[FAILselinux ????????? pg_hba.conf ... failed!
failed!
```

The log file does not contain anything useful that I have not found.
Help to start the server. Before reinstalling the system (Raspbian) worked just fine. And do not even start.

P.S. This is not the first time I am suffering with postgresql.
It is very convenient, but setting is simply disgusting.

Comment: It looks like SElinux related issue - try to disable selinux temporary

Comment: I can confirm what @PavelStehule wrote. I had to disable selinux to see the light.

Comment: That usually means you're doing something odd, like running a database as the `postgres` user outside the default install location. If you stick to how the packages do things then you should not need to disable SELinux.

Comment: @CraigRinger - yes, my advice was disabling selinux temporary to get clean indices, later look to selinux log and fix it. Usually there are wrong rights on files - with selinux the all system is pretty sensitive to "usual" admin operation, but it can be (it should be) fixed relative simply.

Comment: @PavelStehule - In OS Raspbian no file /etc/selinux/config to change the value to SELINUX = disabled. I do not know how to turn off SELinux on ARM.